# Display all Items using for loop - laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I am able to fetch all names of the city belonging to the country being selected, but my issue lies with displaying all the cities in a label form. This is how my output looks like:

**output**

```
["Barcelona","Atlanta"]
```

How can i make the output look this way:

```
Barcelona

Atlanta
```

**HTML**

```
@foreach($countries as $country)
   <div class="panel">  
       {!!$country->city()->pluck('name');!!}             
   </div>
@endforeach
```

PS: New with laravel!

Comment: You seem to have a basic array, so just output `{{ $country }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each country has many cities, so to avoid N+1 problem, load the data first using [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method:

```
$countries = Country::with('cities')->get();
```

Make sure the relationship is `hasMany`:

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(City::class);
}
```

Then iterate over collection to display each city name:

```
@foreach($countries as $country)
    <div class="panel">
        @foreach ($country->cities as $city)
            {{ $city->name }}
        @endforeach            
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties of your model just by using arrows. This would look like:

```
$country->city->name
```